# Spring, Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring framework and Angular JS. I am developing Html files with angular js as fronted and Spring mvc as backend. Please find the dispatcher-servlet configuration as below.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hourforyou" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

First request arrives to Indexcontroller and properly renders the view.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String login() {
    return "pages/login.html";
}
```

}

After validating user in login.html, i am redirecting to home.html. But its not working.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(URL.HOME)
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping
public String getHome() {
    return "pages/home.html";
}
```

My app.js code

```
'use strict';

var App = angular.module('backoffice', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

App.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl : 'home.html',
    controller : 'HomeController'
}).when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl : 'dashboard.html',
    controller : 'DashboardController'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
});
});
```

Request comes to getHome(), but its not redirecting to home.html file. Please any one tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try to redirect to "pages/index.html" in `getHome()` ? The redirection might be done on the Angular app.

Comment: Hi Stephane i have updated my question with my app.js code. Please find

Comment: The `login.html` is not defined is the app.js code ?

Comment: Do you mean ,  i need to define login.html in app.js  so that redirection to home.html will work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this...

Instead of routing in your server side just return a `success/fail/invalid`string to your api request.

Based on which you can route to respective page after validation in angular side.

**In Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String checkLogin(@RequestBody User user) {

    String status = service.login(user);
    return status;// return success or fail or invalid based on your logic in serviceImpl class
}
```

**In app.js**

```
.state('home', {
      url:'/home',
      templateUrl: 'path/to/Home.html',
      controller:'Home'
      })
```

**In login controller**

```
scope.login  = function(user){
                Repository.login(user)
                .then(function (response){
                if(response.data.status = "success")
                {
                    state.go("home");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(" Password is Invalid...");
                    state.go("login");
                }
                });
                };
                }
```

Comment: Welcome Deepak...! Can u accept ans if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. This is what i exactly done in my code. But the solution is i created an index.html file , mentioned ngview directive in a div inside body tag. First Call to spring dispatcher will return index.html.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String login() {
   return "pages/index.html";
}
```

in index.html

```
<html ng-app='backoffice'  ng-cloak>
<head>
<base href="/module-backoffice/">
<head>
   //js files
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-view></div>
 </body
```

in App.js routing

```
when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginController'
})
```

After sucessful login routing

```
.when('/home.html', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller : 'HomeController'
})
```